# How to call function dynamically in ksh

Tags: shell, ksh

How to call a function along with script name at runtime in ksh.

For example: function test

```
function test { echo "shankar" }
```

Script: `emptycheck.ksh`

Run time:

```
./emptycheck.ksh test # <---- Here I want function name (test) here
```

Comment: Never name a function `test`.  That is a shell builtin, and using that name for other things can only lead to confusion.

Comment: How do you get the function into the script's scope? Are you sourcing a file that defines the function? Once you have a solution for _that_, then your `emptycheck.ksh` could just call `"$1"` to invoke the function named in its first argument... but the problem, again, is making sure that the script sources the place the function is defined.

Comment: To explain a different way, calling a function dynamically is easy. Calling a function _defined in the shell's parent process but not in the shell executing the script itself_ is impossible.

Comment: You may want to look up the FPATH environment variable in the Korn shell manual; it sets directories where the shell looks for functions by name.  If you have a function called `FunctionA`, the shell will look for a script called `FunctionA` in one of the directories on `$FPATH` and load that before the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are after, but perhaps this is useful:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

foo() { echo foo; }
bar() { echo bar; }

${1-foo}
$ ./a.sh foo
foo
$ ./a.sh 
foo
$ ./a.sh bar
bar
```

Answer (score -1):

When you do not want to use getopts and have all functions activated, read the functions in your current environment using a dot:

I copy the example of William Pursell with the other syntax:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

foo() { echo Echoing foo; }
bar() { echo Echoing bar; }

$ . a.sh
$ foo
Echoing foo
$ bar
Echoing bar
```

Answer (score -1):

you can name a function "test", but as mentioned, it's dangerous.

and don't bother with the "#! ..." when sourcing a file.  if you ain't running bash when you source it, that won't change the picture.

if you insist on naming a function for an existing command or builtin (there are good reasons to), *then* to use the existing command or builtin, you use the "command" builtin, which says "avoid any alias or function of that name, and go for the default definition".

e.g.  the former "test" is now accessed "command test ..."

therefore, the proper use of the "command" command is inside an overriding function, e.g.

```
function cd {
    # clean up garbage in the current directory, so then:
    command cd $*      # executes the "real" cd, so you can:
    # do whatever useful things you may what to do on arriving in the new one:
    #  e.g.   i do a "dotlib", which sources any ".*rc" files in the current directory.
}
function comment { echo $* 2>/dev/null; }

comment good luck!
```

Comment: `command cd $*` is buggy -- `command cd "$@"` would actually hold arguments together, such that `"Directory Name With Spaces"` would still be passed as a single argument.

Comment: Similarly, `echo "$*"` or `echo "$@"` (in this particular case they're fairly near equivalent, unless IFS is at a non-default value) would be better than `echo $*`, since that way `comment "* hello *"` would emit the asterisks literally rather than replacing them with files in the current directory.

Comment: Also, if you changed from `function cd {` to `cd() {` (and likewise for `function comment {` to `comment() {`), this code would comply with POSIX rather than relying on bash extensions.

Comment: ...beyond that, though, I'm not sure how this helps re: dynamicism in calling conventions. I read the question to be asking how to write wrapper functions able to call arbitrary commands, as opposed to commands with arbitrary arguments.

Comment: I'll agree with the $* as buggy, in what i call "hostile territory".  imagine a script which runs thru files systems of interest replacing blanks with underscore and colon (which 'doz' chokes on) with nothing.   creating a linked directory (on the same fs).   i did this for a wall street fin svc firm where in order for folks on our support desk to deal with log files, with HH:MM:SS names wanted to view them their PCs